# What is a deprecated warning?

Tags: c, pcap, packet-sniffers, sniffing

I am writing a packet sniffer using c and libpcap functions. following is the source code.

```
 #include <pcap.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "YYY.h"
 
 void pcap_fatal(const char *failed_in, const char *errbuf){
         printf("Fata Error in %s: %s\n", failed_in, errbuf);
         exit(1);
 }
  
 int main(){
         struct pcap_pkthdr header;
         const u_char *packet;
         char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
         char *device;
         pcap_t *pcap_handle;
         int i;
 
 
         device = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
         if(device == NULL)
                 pcap_fatal("pcap_lookupdev", errbuf);
         printf("Sniffing of device %s\n", device);
 
         pcap_handle = pcap_open_live(device, 4096, 1, 0, errbuf);
 
         for(i=0;i<3;i++){
                 packet = pcap_next(pcap_handle, &header);
                 printf("Got a %d bute packet\n", header.len);
                 dump(packet, header.len);
         }
         
         pcap_close(pcap_handle);
 }
```

However when I tried to compile it with gcc it gives the following warning as follows.

```
libcap_sniff.c: In function ‘main’:
libcap_sniff.c:20:2: warning: ‘pcap_lookupdev’ is deprecated: use 'pcap_findalldevs' and use the first device [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   20 |  device = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
      |  ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/pcap.h:43,
                 from libcap_sniff.c:1:
/usr/include/pcap/pcap.h:394:16: note: declared here
  394 | PCAP_API char *pcap_lookupdev(char *)
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

can anyone help me with this. I don't yet know what a deprecated warnning is.

Comment: Did you read the warning message? What did you not understand about it?

Comment: https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_lookupdev.3pcap.html

Comment: The authors of that library have marked that function to warn you that you shouldn't be using that function anymore. So generally speaking you should recheck the API to see if there's a better alternative.

Comment: Generally, it means that the mentionned function is now considered unsafe, and that it is *recommended* to use another one.

Comment: @Damien Deprecating a function doesn't generally mean that the deprecated function is "_unsafe_".

Comment: @TedLyngmo In all examples I have in mind, it is the case, and it seems the case here. But I may miss some cases of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gcc has a non-standard extension called [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) which can be used for all manner of things, such as inlining or declaring functions in a certain memory section. They are used by writing `__attribute__ (arg)` after a function *declaration* (not after a function definition).

One of these attributes is called `deprecated`, which tells gcc to give the application programmer a warning about an obsolete function getting called. Optionally, `deprecated` can be given a message argument. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo (void) __attribute__((deprecated("consider using bar instead")));

void foo (void)
{
  puts("foo");
}

int main (void)
{
  foo();
}
```

This gives:

> `warning: 'foo' is deprecated: consider using bar instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]`
> `foo();`

This warning is enabled by default. To shut it up, one needs to explicitly use the compiler option `-Wno-deprecated-declarations`.

---

As for why your specific function is deprecated, you have to consult the (lacking) documentation for it. `man` doesn't mention why it is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pcap_findalldevs` instead of `pcap_lookupdev`.

Deprecating software means that it may be usable but is regarded as obsolete and that it should be avoided. Usually deprecated software has been replaced by an alternative.

GCC has features for marking functions has deprecated. When a program uses a function that is marked as deprecated, GCC warns you about it, so that you can modify the code to use more modern functions. Deprecated functions may be removed in future versions of the software they are part of.

This [documentation](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_lookupdev.3pcap.html) indicates that you can use `pcap_findalldevs` to perform the function of the `pcap_lookupdev` routine.

Answer (score 0):

Beware: the beginning of the question is about the generic *warning*. The correct answer to the actual question is later in the post.

Although the standard only defines the `#error` directive, most common implementations accepts a non fatal `#warning` one. They can be used by libraries writer to raise errors or warnings when *something* can be detected at compilation time.

This just means that the guys from libpcap have *deprecated* usage of `pcap_lookupdev` and that it is likely to be removed in a later version. They just warn users of their library to stop using it in new code.

---

But here a different mechanism is involved. Gnu C compiler (but maybe others) have a specific *attribute* to indicate deprecation. It is intended to be used with the special option `-Wdeprecated-declarations` to switch deprecation warnings on, and `-Wno-deprecated-declaration` to switch them off.

Comment: `-Wdeprecated-declarations` is a gcc option though. Otherwise it would say "#warning text here". So I don't understand how this answer is relevant to the question?

Comment: @Lundin: Look like I did not write the end of the error message when I should have...

Comment: However, I did a `man pcap_lookupdev` and it was perfectly unhelpful. Not saying why it was deprecated or what should be used instead. This is the general problem with open source: non-existent documentation.

Comment: @Lundin: The documentation is not non-existent. Proof of existence is in [Hans Passant’s earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69448054/what-is-a-deprecated-warning-in-c-programming-language#comment122750390_69448054), which links to [documentation](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_lookupdev.3pcap.html) that says `pcap_lookupdev` is replaced by `pcap_findalldevs`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Are you saying that https://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap_lookupdev has not been updated since 2017? I would have thought it pulls `man` straight from some up to date Linux distro.

Comment: @SergeBallesta `pcap_lookupdev()` will probably not be removed for a very long time, if ever, for both source *and* binary compatibility reasons.  It's deprecated, as in "it exists, but we recommend that you don't use it", for the reasons given in the BUGS section of newer versions of its man page.

Comment: @Lundin The Linux man pages project appears to have a more up-to-date version of the `pcap_lookupdev()` man page at https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pcap_lookupdev.3pcap.html.  Perhaps die.net doesn't do as good a job of keeping up. (Corrected version, entered as a separate comment due to StackOverflow's 5-minute rule.)